# Redirect the login page based on domain URL value on React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-modules, url-routing

I have created the Simple React JS with Spring boot JWT authentication application. On my react js application default landing (Index) page was login.js. And I have another login page file named as signin.js.

I want to show the landing pages based on the domain url.

When the user using the domain test.***.com then I needs to show the login.js as landing screen.

if the users using the domain alpha.***.com then I needs to show signin.js as landing screen.

I m new for the reactjs routing.

So anyone kindly assist to achieve my requirement.

Right now I m using simple routes only, I have listed them as follows.

```
<Routes>
      <Route exact path={"/"} element={<Login />} />
      <Route exact path={"/home"} element={<Home />} />
      <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route exact path="/login2" element={<Login_2 />} />
      <Route exact path="/signin" element={<SignIn />} />
      <Route exact path="/register" element={<Register />} />
      <Route exact path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
      <Route path="/user" element={<BoardUser />} />
      <Route path="/mod" element={<BoardModerator />} />
      <Route path="/admin" element={<BoardAdmin />} />
    </Routes>
```

Thanks in advance